# How do I find a file inside the current directory in x86 Windows Assembly

Tags: windows, file, assembly, x86, fasm

I am having a few issues with my code. I am trying to read both of the PE headers inside of an executable file. However, when I invoke ReadFile, it sets `[hFile]` to 5A, which is not the handle I put inside from `CreateFile`. From what I understand, `ReadFile` should not change this in any way. However, when I store the handle inside another variable and use it to set the file pointer, the next `ReadFile` instruction still gives me the `MZ` header instead of the `PE` header, which is located at offset 3C from the `MZ` header.

Summary: `ReadFile` changes my handle, `SetFilePointer` sees the change as an invalid handle, `SetFilePointer` does not change the pointer for the next read when given a valid handle.

```
format PE console 4.0
entry start

include 'win32ax.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable

thisFile db "thisfile.exe",0
read db ?
hFile dd ?

section '.text' data readable executable

start:
;========Open File================
invoke CreateFile,thisFile,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,\
                  OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0
mov [hFile],eax

;========MZ HEADER================
invoke ReadFile,[hFile],read,2,NULL,0 ; = MZ, , however, changes [hFile]
                                      ;to 5A? Why does it change it?
invoke printf,read

;========PE HEADER================
invoke SetFilePointer,[hFile],03Ch,0,FILE_CURRENT ; = 0, beginning of file ATM
                                                  ;Should make next read = PE
invoke ReadFile,[hFile],read,3,NULL,0 ; = PE

invoke printf,read

invoke getchar
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're reading 2 bytes into `read`:

```
invoke ReadFile,[hFile],read,2,NULL,0
```

But look at how you've declared `read`:

```
read db ?
```

That's a single byte. So the second byte you're reading with `ReadFile` will get written into whatever follows `read` in memory, which happens to be `hFile`. Thus, you're overwriting the least significant byte of `hFile`.

There's another place in your code where you're trying to read 3 bytes into `read`, but I guess that will fail since by then your `hFile` will be invalid.

What you need to do is to reserve more space for `read`, as much as you ever plan on storing in it. Let's say that you want 4 bytes, you could get that with:

```
read db 4 dup(0)
```

or

```
read: times 4 db 0
```

or

```
read rb 4
```

or

```
read dd ?
```

---

Since you're passing `read` to `printf` as a string, keep in mind that strings are expected to be NUL-terminated.

Comment: So for the past few weeks, I have been getting lucky in the fact none of my data was overwritten. Thank you for clearing up one of my misconceptions. I always assumed that `abc DB ?` meant that it was going to make space for what I put into it.

Comment: A smaller sub-question, however. In assembly, how would I handle data that I won't know how big it is. Like a filename. Because if I did `filename DB 256 dup (0)` for every variable of unknown length, it wold cause my program to bloat. Is `GlobalAlloc` my answer?

Comment: Yes, at some point you'll probably need some sort of heap allocation routine. There are several of them in Windows (`LocalAlloc`, `GlobalAlloc`, `HeapAlloc`, ...). You can probably find out on MSDN which of them that would be best to use for your purposes.